# LIMIT with SKIP Value using SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to get the median of a numeric column using mySQL.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N
LIMIT SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(*)/2) FROM STATION,1
```

Where LAT_N is the column name that I want to check and STATION is the table name. I got the following error, But I could not understand which syntax is wrong.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(*)/2) FROM STATION),1' at line 3
```

Could you help me to find the syntax error? If possible I would like to calculate the median using the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use prepared statements, as Limit only accepts Numbers

```
 SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(*)/2) INTO @a FROM STATION;
SET @s = 'SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N
LIMIT ?,1';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Does that mean we can't use query to get a number to be used as an input in limit?

Comment: Limit needs a Number like 1 2,3 and doesn allow variables or SELECT resultset, so , you must use prepared staments, if you want to use Limit

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions instead:

```
SELECT LAT_N
FROM (SELECT S.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N) AS SEQNUM
      FROM STATION S
     ) S
WHERE SEQNUM = FLOOR(CNT / 2);
```